# Please create the "level" tag for this question

Tags: support, tags

The "levels" tag is already used for the exposure/curves adjustment tool common to photo-manipulation tool. Stack Exchange (reasonably enough) won't let me create a singular tag when the plural already exists. But here, I want it to mean something different. Please someone create the tag [level](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/level) and add it to this question.

[How accurate are cheap hotshoe bubble levels?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21889/how-accurate-are-cheap-hotshoe-bubble-levels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. Out of curiosity, are you sure you couldn't actually create the tag? Even though it brings up a list of suggestions, I just hit escape and saved, and it created the tag. I'm not sure if that is actually a mod ability, or just how you have to do it in general.

Comment: That's normal level behaviour (at least for me on another site where I'm not so moddy, and have much less reputation than @mattdm has here)

Comment: Yeah, I tried and it would not let me. Thanks!

Comment: @mattdm: Your welcome. :)